# How do we create a reusable block that share architecture in a single model but learn different set of weight in the single model in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using tensorflow.keras and want to know if it is possible to create reusable blocks of inbuilt Keras layers. For example, I would like to repeatedly use the same set of layers (that able to learn the different weights) at a different position in a model. I would like to use the following block at different times in my model.

```
keep_prob_=0.5
input_features=Input(shape=(29, 1664))
Imortant_features= SelfAttention(activation='tanh',
      kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.), kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform' 
     (input_features)

drop3=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(keep_prob_)(Imortant_features)
Layer_norm_feat=tf.keras.layers.Add()([input_features, drop3])
Layer_norm=tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=-1)(Layer_norm_feat)
ff_out=tf.keras.layers.Dense(Layer_norm.shape[2], activation='relu')(Layer_norm)
ff_out=tf.keras.layers.Dense(Layer_norm.shape[2])(ff_out)
drop4=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(keep_prob_)(ff_out)
Layer_norm_input=tf.keras.layers.Add()([Layer_norm, drop4])
Attention_block_out=tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=-1)(Layer_norm_input)
intraEpoch_att_block=tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_features, outputs=Attention_block_out)
```

I have read about creating custom layers in Keras but I did not find the documentation to be clear enough. I want to reuse the sub-model which able to learn the different set of weight in a single functional API model in tensorflow.keras.

Comment: Here is some advice to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code (I removed SelfAttention, so add it back):

```
import tensorflow as tf

class my_model(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(my_model, self).__init__()

    keep_prob_=0.5
    input_features=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(29, 1664))
    drop3=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(keep_prob_)(input_features)
    Layer_norm_feat=tf.keras.layers.Add()([input_features, drop3])
    Layer_norm=tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=-1)(Layer_norm_feat)
    ff_out=tf.keras.layers.Dense(Layer_norm.shape[2], activation='relu')(Layer_norm)
    ff_out=tf.keras.layers.Dense(Layer_norm.shape[2])(ff_out)
    drop4=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(keep_prob_)(ff_out)
    Layer_norm_input=tf.keras.layers.Add()([Layer_norm, drop4])
    Attention_block_out=tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(axis=-1)(Layer_norm_input)
    self.intraEpoch_att_block=tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_features, outputs=Attention_block_out)
    
  def call(self, inp, training=False):
    x = self.intraEpoch_att_block(inp)
    return x

model1 = my_model()
model2 = my_model()
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if you are happy with it

Comment: Please explain, the reason behind 'training=False',  passed in the call function?

Comment: It is default parameter - to avoid calling with 'training=False' when evaluating the model